# Installing Miniconda via a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Miniconda via a shell script I am preparing to set up a working environment inside a virtual machine.

However it appears that for the installation of Miniconda to be completely independent of human input, I need to scroll down a text; the usual methods of prompt answering appear to be ineffective.

for example,

```
yes 'yes' |  ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

as well as

```
(echo '\n' && echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo '\n' &&echo 'yes' ) | ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Do not advance in the text scroll, only manually pressing 'enter' work for me - which of course defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to circumvent the installation interface it appears I just should have asked it nicely.

The creators of miniconda already created a solution to this problem - just use `-b` argument.

I used

```
bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b
```

And it works perfectly.